# Log files not being generated by chainlink

Tags: linux, chainlink

I build my v 1.1.1 nodes from source and cannot find the logs when I run the executable - logs in user friendly format are supposed to generate in the $ROOT directory, according to the configuration settings here https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-nodes/v1/configuration#logging but without $ROOT set and with $ROOT set, no logs are appearing.
(They should show in ~/.chainlink - which is autogenned and has the secret in it when chainlink runs)

Not sure why there are no logs?

I also tried this by setting $ROOT to another directory ( ~/chainlinlops ) when I restarted the server still no logs (tho the secret file was generated there )

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) You should not just request a ready solution. SO is for helping solve specific errors, after you've shown your effort solving them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.env` set `LOG_TO_DISK=true`

Comment: Perfect, this worked when I set it in the /etc/environment file in Ubuntu